# How Work Done is Calculated for Changing Direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, vectors, displacement

I know work done is equal to product of force, displacement and cosine of angle between them. But that formula works only when we assume that the force is constant during displacement and it acts  so long the body moves and also when the direction of force and displacement is constant. But how should I calculate work done if the direction of force or displacement is changing. So in this case there would be no constant angle between them and so dot product won't work as I don't know the cosine value and at this point I have got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Work done by something in presence of a force is given by

$$W_d = \int_{a}^b (\vec{F}.\vec{dx} )$$

In this case $\vec{F}$ can be any function of X and work done is found using integration in cases where angles are changing constantly.
Even though the angles are changing, we care only about the displacement of the object not the path taken (At least for conservative forces).

Answer (score 1):

I apologize in advance if this too simplistic - I am still getting a feel for Physics Stack Exchange. It is often not clear to me what level some of these questions are aimed at.

This seems too simplistic but you don't mean something like force, displacement and the angle between the two being functions of time do you?

Something like this:
$$ W \left( t \right) = \int F \left( t \right). x \left( t \right) dx $$

Because, if that were the case, without knowing how $F$ or $\phi$ vary with time, I do not see that this can be computed.
Edit: Or as MMS 05 posted above, if you knew the expression for F(x) as a (presumably continuous and continuously differentiable) function of x, you could calculate W(t).

Actually I have to check Thomas' Calculus re: vector integrals. Or rather I see what I was mucking up. The cosine does not have to be explicitly included when F and x are expressed as vectors.
F would be in the form of
F = (Fi i+ Fj j+ Fk k). Similarly,
x = (xi i+ xj j+ xk k)

(I will change these to equations later).

If you had those expressions then you could compute,

$$ W \left( t \right) = \int_{0}^{t} F \left( t \right). x \left( t \right) x' \left( t \right) dt $$

for the time-interval from $0$ to $t$.

Edit: Never mind-MMS 05 answered it far more elegantly. This is redundant, but oh well..

Comment: Thanks again ZaellixA! That is easier to read.

Comment: Just make sure to double check the edits to make sure that no mistakes were done when converting the original equations to MathJax. Additionally, it is quite good to use MathJax since it makes your equations way easier to read and is extremely similar to LaTeX (which is easy to learn if you don't already as there are many tutorials and texts out there).

Comment: Thanks..got it! I have never used MathJax so I was looking at that. These were fine, but it need just be the dot product of F and x. I can see how clunky the expression looks once the equation editor is used. Thanks again-I will use it in future posts. Makes it so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the line integral seen in vector calculus. You can define the work as
$$W=\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$
where $d\vec{r}$ depends on the parameterize curve and $\vec{F}$ can be a constant vector or can vary along the path. As a simple as example, suppose you want to determine the work done by gravity from a projectile that starts at the max height and is moving to the right. You can show that the height can be expressed in terms of the range as

$$y=h_{max}-\frac{g}{v_{0x}^2}x^2$$
You can show that

$$\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int \vec{F}\cdot\left< dx,dy,dz\right>$$

In 2D, this is just

$$\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int \vec{F}\cdot\left< dx,dy\right>$$

We can write $dy$ from the trajectory of the projectile as

$$dy=-\frac{2gx}{v_{0x}^2}dx$$

Supposing that you let $\vec{F}=\left<0,-mg\right>$ and puting everything in

$$\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int \left<0,-mg\right>\cdot\left< dx,-\frac{2gx}{v_{0x}^2}dx\right>$$

Applying the dot-product, we get

$$\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int  0dx+mg\frac{2gx}{v_{0x}^2}dx=\int mg\frac{2gx}{v_{0x}^2}dx$$

Running the integral from the $h_{max}$ to the “ground” $(h=0)$, or from $x=0$ to $x=\sqrt{\frac{h_{max}v_{0x}^2}{g}}$, we get

$$\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{h_{max}v_{0x}^2}{g}}} mg\frac{2gx}{v_{0x}^2}dx=mgh_{max}$$

whose answer should look familiar to you.

The line integral can also be expressed in terms of the cosine you mentioned. Your job would be to parameterize the angle in that situation. Sometimes this is obvious and sometimes it’s not.